# Installation of Yii Extensions

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii and i would like to know how to install extensions, i.e the EHttpClient.
I have already searched the Internet but haven't found a good How-To.

Thanks for your instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install the extension u just extract the extension to protected/extension folder thats it

Comment: That doesn't work. I extracted the extension to protected/extenstion/EHttpClient. When i use new EHttpClient in my controller, i get the following error: include(EHttpClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

A better explanation could be made if an example was given, so here is an example.

If you wanted to use [Bootstrap](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/), you need to download it and place that folder into de protected/extensions.

Then, in your config/main.php, do [this](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html).

Basicaly, you need to tell Yii to use that extension in the main.php.

In this case, it is just:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
//note this is **outside** of *return array(*



return array(
....
    'theme'=>'bootstrap',
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'components'=>array(
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
    ),
....
);
```

Also, in Bootstrap's particular case, in your layout, you need to register the CSS and JS of the extension with:

```
Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
```

That is is all I believe.